# uploading image to Flickr using API issue

Tags: php, api, flickr

I have a doubt regarding uploading image to Flickr using API. While uploading do we need to include the signature as a parameter like we do in token fetch? If so, which all parameters need to be included in calculating the signature?

I went through the documentation but they haven't specified which all parameters are needed for signature calculation. Because of this I'm facing Invalid_signature error.

Answer (score 0):

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxapi_keyxxxxxxxxxxauth_tokenxxxxxxxxxxxformatphp_serialmethodflickr.people.getPhotosuser_idxxxxxxxxxx
```

Above example is used to generate signature for pulling the photos of the user. As you can see, all the parameters required to call the flickr api is required. You will have to generate the md5 hash of the above string, which will be the signature for the api request.

The first "xxxxxxx" part of the string (before api_key) is the api_secret. Fill the remaining with the api_key, auth_token(access_key) and user_id.

For uploading pics,

```
xxxxxxxxapi_keyxxxxxxxauth_tokenxxxxxxxxxtitleUploadTest
```

Above string is used to generate signature to upload a pic with title "UploadTest". If you include other parameters, you will have to include those parameters (example: description, tags) and generate signature using md5. Better use library to perform these tasks. I am using phpflickr class (phpflickr.com). Hope it helps.....